# Node js promise result use in other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new in node js and i need result of my first query as a parameter in another function. 
Here my model:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        db.query(sql,
         (err, result) => {
           if (err) {
             return reject(err)
           }
           return resolve(result)
        });
   });
```

I need something like this

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    db.query(sql)
    .then(rows.map(row =>{ 
            return arr[row.id] = this.getProduct(row.id);
    }))
})
```

Comment: `resolve(result.map(...))`…?

Comment: What is `db.query(sql)
    .then(…)`, is that the same function you called with a callback in the first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Use Async/Await.

You can make a `generic` queryDb function which will call db and fetch result for any query.
`mainFunction` will wait for `await` to finish and fetch result which you can use in line below it.
Code also looks clean and easy to understand.
Something like this,

```
async function mainFunction(){ 
  try{
    const query = `INSERT INTO aaa xxxxxx`;
    const result = await queryDb(query);
    //do whatever with the result;
    this.getProduct(result);

  }
  catch(e){
    //catch error
  }
}

function queryDb(sql){
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    db.query(sql,
     (err, result) => {
       if (err) {
         return reject(err)
       }
       return resolve(result)
    });
  })
}
```